# What sampler do you use?

Tags: sound-design, sampler, sound-effects, sound-libraries

Hi,

Just a little survey here.

I was wondering what sampler do you use or planning to use specifically for sound design?
N.I. Kontakt 3-4 or 5, Avid Structure, Apple Logic EXS24, Camelaudio Alchemy, Cubase Halion, MOTU Machfive, Ableton Live Sampler...

Do you have any interest for a HQ sound effects libraries like foley (footsteps, clothing, sports, or any sfx time consuming to sync...)

Thanks to all

Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Akai S3000. Also want an Emu Emulator, pretty much don't care which version, and would give my right arm for a Fairlight CMI!

Answer (score 1):

I've only used Structure LE as a quick footstep sampler when there's no time to record custom foley, works great. Here's how I use it:

Pull any appropriate footstep file into your timeline, use Beat Detective to separate into regions, grab the regions, drag and drop into a Structure channel, select how you want to fill the keyboard (white keys only, black keys only, chromatically), start playing along with picture. Turns out reasonably well.

So in that regard, certainly, I'd love HQ foley FX. Obviously, they won't beat recording actual custom foley though.

Comment: TI'll had some little "extras" on this. 4 layers (sloppy, normal, fast, run) with 26 samples each round robbin presets on one key, plus 26 round robin upstairs samples on one key, 26 round robin downstairs on another key. And the same 4 layers spread on the white keys, plus moves on black keys. All with differents kind of shoes and surfaces, ready to go. 

Do you think that there would be interest in that kind of library?

Thanks Steve, I appreciate.


Comment: Yes please? Especially for quick layouts

Answer (score 0):

I have Kontakt 3, but I admittedly don't know how to use it as anything more than a midi instrument (any links would be awesome).

Comment: Well Kontakt is very deep and that's why i'm building presets for sound designer. Thanks for the reply Dave.

Answer (score 0):

I started on an EMU-32 hardware sampler, then an Emu E5000 (ooh, with those gigantic Iomega Zip disks), then moved to Logic's EXS24 once I went nearly all-virtual with my instruments, which I find very fast for setting up patches and having pretty good routing options...good balance of complexity vs. immediacy. However, now I'm probably going to move to Kontakt in the next year or two, as that seems to be one of the most popular cross-DAW samplers with oodles of routing and filtering options. Many, or most, sample pack releases tend to be targeting Kontakt as a release platform these days anyway...

Comment: ....loading....
...please wait...

;o)

Thanks NoiseJokey

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Apple Logic EXS24 sampler since I predominantly use Logic Pro X as my current DAW of choice. I've only ever used the built-in sounds that it comes with.

Recently I did some work supplying UI Sound Effects for a sporting device, I would've saved a lot of time if I had bought a UI SFX library.

In the past I've used the classic AKAI S950 hardware sampler, great unique sound but very time consuming. I remember the times I had to get out the calculator to time stretch by "percentage". Also very little storage space, I remember it being really frustrating, but there was a certain satisfaction to working with such tight constraints.

I guess I could probably do more "musically" with the ESX24 if I bought some kind of intuitive drum pad controller, at the moment I use an AXIOM-49 controller keyboard which fine for general purpose things.